# CGI combo Cant select the right value

Tags: cgi, popupmenu

my cgi popup menu only selects the first element of the array of values. This is the code for its creation :

```
$q->popup_menu({ 
-id=> 'id',                       
-name   => 'name',                      
-class  => 'comboClass',                      
-values => [@aArray1],                     
-labels => \%aArray2                    
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove [] and to add \:

```
-values => [@aArray1],
```

To

```
-values => \@aArray1,
```